When Postman tests GetNewAccesToken in AUTHORIZATION_CODE mode, an error occurs: [invalid_request] OAuth 2.0 Parameter: code_challenge
When testing the AUTHORIZATION_CODE mode of oauth2, Postman prompts an error message: Authorization request failed: [invalid_request] OAuth 2.0 Parameter: code_challenge. The Callback URL I set is https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback.
When I click GetNewAccessToken, the browser also displays the following page:enter image description here
At this time, the browser address url ishttps://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback?error=invalid_request&error_description=OAuth%202.0%20Parameter%3A%20code_challenge&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdatatracker.ietf.org%2Fdoc%2Fhtml%2Frfc7636%23section-4.4.1&state=1234
It should have redirected to the login page, but it didn't:http://locahost:9000/login
Below is my authserver registered client：
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient clientCreClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("oidc-client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .scopes(scopeConfig -> scopeConfig.addAll(List.of(OidcScopes.OPENID,"ADMIN","USER")))
                .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder().accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                        .accessTokenFormat(OAuth2TokenFormat.SELF_CONTAINED).build())
                .build();

        RegisteredClient authCodeClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("oidc-client2")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret2")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .redirectUri("https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID).scope(OidcScopes.EMAIL)
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireProofKey(true).build())
                .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder().accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                        .refreshTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofHours(8)).reuseRefreshTokens(false)
                        .accessTokenFormat(OAuth2TokenFormat.SELF_CONTAINED).build())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(clientCreClient,authCodeClient);
    }

Then my postman configuration:
enter image description here
Then the error message output by my idea:
org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationException: OAuth 2.0 Parameter: code_challenge_method
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider.throwError(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider.java:407) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider.throwError(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider.java:384) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.authentication.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider.java:152) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter.java:185) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.oidc.web.OidcLogoutEndpointFilter.doFilterInternal(OidcLogoutEndpointFilter.java:124) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerContextFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthorizationServerContextFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230) ~[spring-security-config-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar:6.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:905) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.30.jar:10.1.30]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
15:03:38.046 TRACE [http-nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.o.s.a.w.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter - Redirecting to client with error
15:03:38.046 DEBUG [http-nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback?error=invalid_request&error_description=OAuth%202.0%20Parameter%3A%20code_challenge_method&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdatatracker.ietf.org%2Fdoc%2Fhtml%2Frfc7636%23section-4.4.1&state=1234
15:03:38.046 TRACE [http-nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.s.w.h.w.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]


and
15:05:23.972 TRACE [http-nio-9000-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]

If I missed some details that you might be interested in, I'll add them to yours.
To be honest, I have no idea. After all, I am not familiar with springoauth2 at all. I hope you can give me some advice.
